# php cronjob doesn't write to file

Tags: php, cron

i'm writing a simple php script which made some stuffs every hour and write a log file.
The issue is cronjob doesnt write to log file, is it a permission issue? is it a path issue?

I have an hosting service by siteground. Script file has permission to write, read and execute.
I've already try to set a cronjob which just send me an email without write a file and it's running.
Thanks

This is my code:

```
//
//some stuffs here
//
$file='www.domainname.com/logfile.csv';
$handle = fopen ($file, "w");
fwrite($handle, "hello, i done some stuffs");
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Is this a cronejob problem or a php problem. Does the file work if you run it yourself?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't edit files that are located on a webserver with `fwrite`

Comment: Then why would the function exist @gogaz? I edit and write files on web server's all of the time with `fwrite()` unless there is a *permissions* problem.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It seems very strange to write to a file using HTTP protocol, doesn't it ?

Comment: Perhaps, but not unheard of @gogaz He probably has a path issue or a permissions issue which he would find if he looked in the error logs.

Comment: I think you're talking across each other - writing to a file *located* at `www.domainname.com/logfile.csv` isn't possible. Writing to a file *called* `www.domainname.com/logfile.csv` is. It's not obvious (to me, at least), which one the question is referring to.

Comment: OK, just some explanation: csv and script files are hosted on my siteground space in public html section. Script should makes some stuffs and just writes a log file there (log file name is "logfile.csv"). Are there security issue writing a file? (permissions: write=>user, read and execute=>user,group,world).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the absolute or relative path to the file on the file system.

example: -

```
$handle = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/logfile.csv' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed file path, script wrote a file if i run page manually but scheduled cronjob still not write file.

Comment: check the file permission

Comment: yep, i changed them to: write (user & world) but nothing. Should i change something else, like using ftp? how do you usually do? I have no error logs

Answer (score 0):

Generally having a writable file in the web servers directory is a bad idea. If your program can write to the file, then the web server can write to the file too. That opens the possibility for someone to overwrite the file through the web server. At best you lose data from being over written. At worst it allows remote code execution.

It would be better to put the writable files outside the web server directory.

```
<Parent directory>
            <Place for writable files>
            <Web server directory>
```

In your programs run from the webserver you just need to specify the path to the files.

Relative Path

```
$relitivePath = '/../writeDir';
$handle = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $relitivePath . '/logfile.csv' );
```

Full Path

```
$fullPath = '/somedir/ParentDir/writeDir'
$handle = fopen( $fullPath . '/logfile.csv' );
```

Running from cron a bit different than running it from shell. The environment you are use to is not set up like yo have when sshing in. Your going to have to list the full path or set up the environment.

```
$fullPath = '/somedir/ParentDir/writeDir'
$handle = fopen( $fullPath . '/logfile.csv' );
```

To get your full path

When ssh'ed in:

cd to the directory where the file located.

Do a pwd this will print the current working directory path.

Use that path in like above.

In the program it is a good idea to turn error reporting on.

You also don't want to have the program you call from cron in the web directory.

I see your service provider has a way to email any output from cron. That will help with error reporting.